# Cannot see ActionBar toggle button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-togglebutton

Even after coding it, I'm not able to see toggle button in the preview. Am I missing something?

I want to implement navigation drawer on that toggle button, it will open from right to left and on again clicking it it will close.

Below is my code:

```
public class entryActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private String[] mMenuItems;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_entry);

        //https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html
        mMenuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_items);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mMenuItems));
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);


        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.open,
                R.string.close
        ){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

set this in onCreate method.

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Showing back icon button not toggle one, and on click of that button, app is crashing..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [`setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled%28boolean%29) just like the way you `setHomeButtonEnabled()`

For Hamburger menu option: http://codetheory.in/android-navigation-drawer/

Comment: It showed the button with back symbol, but I want it to be hamburger menu..
and on pressing the button, app is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

Check the full example: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Well it did work, however when drawer pulls out, application stops working.

Comment: What's the exception? Are you using support library? Try changing `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: Don't know the exception, but I'm targeting above API 16 so it should not cause support library problem. I tried with updated code, app is still crashing.